# Do 谢 and 写 sound different (ignoring the tones)?

Tags: difference, pronunciation

I'm aware that [谢](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%B0%A2) (xiè​) and [写](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%86%99) (xiě​) are theoretically meant to sound the same (ignoring tones):

> 谢 has the bopomofo/zhuyin ㄒㄧㄝˋ
> 写 has the bopomofo/zhuyin ㄒㄧㄝˇ

But, to my ear at least, when people say 谢 it sounds like it rhymes with "ear", and when people say 写 it sounds like it rhymes with "air".  They genuinely sound quite different to me.  Maybe I'm just wrong about this, so...

**Question**: Do 谢 and 写 sound different (ignoring the tones)?

Comment: Not answering your question, just my two cents that might help with your Mandarin pronunciation: to my ear (I'm a Mainlander), 谢/写 rhymes with neither "ear" nor "air". It rhymes with the "ye" part of "yes".

Comment: Maybe would help to clarify what English dialect you speak.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are the same to the native ears. But I do have a theory why you feel like that.

Tones affect the length of a syllable. Tone 3 is the longest one, while Tone 4 is very short.

The glide /j/ is always short. With Tone 3, the prolonged time is achieved mainly by the main vowel /e/, so you hear /e/ more. With Tone 4, the syllable is short, cutting the time of vowel /e/, and /j/ is more catchy to your ears.